# How to prevent one iframe from working under another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using an iframe video system with tabs to separate them, the problem I had was that all iframes loaded when you entered that section. I found this answer among many others that could not solve the problem of simultaneous loading [To Load a video embed using "onclick" function to optimize a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060892/to-load-a-video-embed-using-onclick-function-to-optimize-a-web-page) but now the problem I have is that using the solution by jquery to choose option 1 (iframe) loads normally but if I press option 2 both continue loading, ie, option 1 continues loading under the other that was pressed.

The system where I'm applying it is Datalife Engine on a .tpl file, and jquery 1.8.2 that I can change it to a more current one but the result is the same

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myButton").on("click", function() {
    var $iframe = $("#myIframe");
    $iframe.attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6wUxpFu9Wvo");
    $iframe.show();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myButton1").on("click", function() {
    var $iframe = $("#myIframe");
    $iframe.attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6wUxpFu9Wvo");
    $iframe.show();
  });
});
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.close').click(function(){      
        $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
    });
});
</script>
<iframe id="myIframe" width="560" height="315" style="display:none;" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<button id="myButton" class="close">Load video</button>

<iframe id="myIframe1" width="560" height="315" style="display:none;" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<button id="myButton1" class="close">Load video</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The final result is that option 1 is still loading below another option, I was trying options to reload iframes but those who bring videos with autoplay continue to load below the new chosen one

Comment: Both buttons have 2 handles assigned to them. On click they call the #myButton and .close handlers. What exactly is the close method doing? setting the source of iframe from the src of itself? #myButton1 is also referring to the same #myIframe. Why do you need 2 iFrames? why not just change the source of the the same ONE iframe based on the button clicked?

Comment: Are you trying to unload one of the loaded `iframe` when the user clicks a button not connected to that `iframe`? Your code for the button specific click points to the same, while the "close" button click loads all `iframe`with all sources. Also, you don't need to have a new `onready` wrapper for each click handler definition. They can be all in the same one.

Comment: I'm still learning in jquery so I didn't know that you can load several srcs into a single iframe and turn them for individual playback. What I'm trying to do is to prevent in some way to keep playing when trying to display another option, I currently use 6 options via iframe and is the problem I have and "solved" with onclick="reloadPage();" in a separate button but it is not optimal me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same iFrame and change it's src on click of several buttons.
Following is an example similar to yours with one iFrame and 3 buttons. Each button loads a different video in the same iFrame. I am using youtube video id to differentiate the videos.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".myButton").on("click", function() {
    var videoId = $(this).data('video-id');
    var $iframe = $("#myIframe");

    $iframe.attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="myIframe" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="border: 1px solid black;"></iframe>
<br />
<button id="button1" class="myButton" data-video-id="6wUxpFu9Wvo">Load video 1</button>
<button id="button2" class="myButton" data-video-id="z5jnpb_lp4w">Load video 2</button>
<button id="button3" class="myButton" data-video-id="6wUxpFu9Wv2">Load video 3</button>
```

Comment: This is working totally perfect, thank you very much for your help and that of the other two people who also gave an idea, I had been thinking about taking the option of a single iframe but your help resolved all the doubts I had ... I could even adapt it without any problem to the span I was using. A question that I am left echoing, can you add an image to replace the darkness in the iframe? Thank you very much, I love you eternally

Comment: You are welcome @Berker. I am not sure what darkness in iframe you are referring to. You can set src='about:blank' to have a blank page or yes you can have an image if you make a new html page on your server and use it's URL as the source. An iframe is just a window that opens a url.